# Tag value from xml using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

In this below example, say file.xml
There are values inside tags return code=" " I need the values inside `<Port name="write_qwe">` ONLY.

```
<Main display="NORMAL">
    <Port name="read_abc" exe="NO">
        <input>
            <struct file="C:\temp" sign="id1"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <return code="33" shortmsg="Implementation not found for commande."/>
        </output>
    </Port>
    <Port name="write_qwe" exe="NO">
        <input>
            <struct file="C:\temp" id="id1"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <return code="1" shortmsg="NOTEXECUTED" longmsg="Not execute due to previous error"/>
        </output>
    </Port>
    <Port name="read_abc" exe="NO">
        <input>
            <struct file="C:\temp" sign="id2"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <return code="66" shortmsg="Implementation"/>
        </output>
    </Port>
    <Port name="write_qwe" exe="NO">
        <input>
            <struct file="C:\temp" id="id2"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <return code="0" shortmsg="NOTEXECUTED" />
        </output>
    </Port>
</Main>
```

I need to get the value of the
       `<return code" ">`
 which is inside 
    `<port name="write_*">`
  and inside 
    `<output>` .
In this example I need to get values "1" and "0" .

Comment: I'd suggest to use `DOM`,`XPath`

Comment: try this it will help you..............


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773012/getting-xml-node-text-value-with-java-dom

Comment: @paul I have done the code till, wheather it checks "read_abc" or "write_qwe"

Comment: @Sath : yes, I checked,but it doesnot give the values inside a tag (return code=" ")

Comment: And what difficulty are you having performing the check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath is probably the way to go here.

I have put the xml file as a resource but you may have it in a file structure.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
ClassLoader loader = XmlTestReader.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream("test.xml");
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
```

Then create an XPath expression.

```
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/Main/Port[@name='write_qwe']/output/return/@code");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The XPath expression `/Main/Port[@name='write_qwe']/output/return/@code` will find all `code` attributes where the `Port`'s attribute `name` is `write_qwe`.

And now you can iterate over the nodes like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nl.item(i);
    System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());
}
```

You can restrict the XPath to `/Main/Port[@name='write_qwe']/output/return` if you want the whole `<return>` node instead.

And iterating like this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nl.item(i);
    System.out.println(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("code").getNodeValue());
}
```

---

**Edit**

As suggested by the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172390/tag-value-from-xml-using-java/12173592#comment16295361_12173592) by [Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan) it might be better to use an `InputSource` as input to `XPathExpression#evaluate()` instead:

```
ClassLoader loader = XmlTestReader.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("test.xml");
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream);

XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/Main/Port[@name='write_qwe']/output/return/@code");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(inputSource , XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: +1 - But I would recommend calling the `evaluate` method that takes an `InputSource` instead.  This gives the XPath implementation the chance to not build a DOM if it doesn't need one.  This can lead to a performance improvement.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I added your suggestion to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont have any problem in using xpath ,then you can try this :

You have to give the path of your xml file in the argument.

```
   XPathReader reader = new XPathReader("FileName.xml");

   // To get a xml attribute.
   String expression = "/Main/Port/output/@code";

   System.out.println(reader.read(expression,XPathConstants.STRING) + "n");
```

Answer (score 0):

if your XML is a String, Then you can do the following:

```
String xml = ""; //Populated XML String....
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
```

If your XML is in a file, then Document document will be instantiated like this:

```
Document document = builder.parse(new File("file.xml"));
```

The `document.getDocumentElement()` returns you the node that is the document element of the document (in your case `<config>`).

Once you have a rootElement, you can access the element's attribute (by calling rootElement.getAttribute() method), etc. For more methods on java's `org.w3c.dom.Element`

For further clarification view this link it helps you much...

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

cheers..!