# Getting value of child node from XML in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

My xml file looks like this

```
 <InNetworkCostSharing>
                <FamilyAnnualDeductibleAmount>
                    <Amount>6000</Amount>
                </FamilyAnnualDeductibleAmount>
                <IndividualAnnualDeductibleAmount>
                    <NotApplicable>Not Applicable</NotApplicable>
                </IndividualAnnualDeductibleAmount>
                <PCPCopayAmount>
                    <CoveredAmount>0</CoveredAmount>
                </PCPCopayAmount>
                <CoinsuranceRate>
                    <CoveredPercent>0</CoveredPercent>
                </CoinsuranceRate>
                <FamilyAnnualOOPLimitAmount>
                    <Amount>6000</Amount>
                </FamilyAnnualOOPLimitAmount>
                <IndividualAnnualOOPLimitAmount>
                    <NotApplicable>Not Applicable</NotApplicable>
                </IndividualAnnualOOPLimitAmount>
 </InNetworkCostSharing>
```

I am trying to get Amount value from `<FamilyAnnualDeductibleAmount>` and also from `<FamilyAnnualOOPLimitAmount>`. How do i get those values in java?

Comment: You need to navigate the tree structure to extract those values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution with this question from stackoverflow

[Getting XML Node text value with Java DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773012/getting-xml-node-text-value-with-java-dom)

Answer (score 4):

You may use two XPath queries `/InNetworkCostSharing/FamilyAnnualDeductibleAmount` and `InNetworkCostSharing/FamilyAnnualOOPLimitAmount` or just get the node `InNetworkCostSharing` and retrieve the values of its two direct children.

Solution using XPath:

```
// load the XML as String into a DOM Document object
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream("YOUR XML".getBytes());
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(bis);

// XPath to retrieve the content of the <FamilyAnnualDeductibleAmount> tag
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/InNetworkCostSharing/FamilyAnnualDeductibleAmount/text()");
String familyAnnualDeductibleAmount = (String)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this(use getElementsByTagName to get the parent nodes and then get the value be reaching out to child node):

```
   File xmlFile = new File("NetworkCost.xml");
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile );
   doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

   NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("FamilyAnnualDeductibleAmount");
   String familyDedAmount = nList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent();

   nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("FamilyAnnualOOPLimitAmount");
   String familyAnnualAmount = 
                            nList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent();
```

Comment: @yogsma I think its `item(0)` in child nodes as well. Change and try. If still fails, let me know, I will try myself and let you know. Its definitely those indexes.

Comment: I tried changing it ..I hope you noted there "Amount" tag after FamilyAnnualDeductibleAmount tag.

Answer (score 1):

StAX based solution:

```
    XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader rdr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("test.xml"));
    while (rdr.hasNext()) {
        if (rdr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
            if (rdr.getLocalName().equals("FamilyAnnualDeductibleAmount")) {
                rdr.nextTag();
                int familyAnnualDeductibleAmount = Integer.parseInt(rdr.getElementText());
                System.out.println("familyAnnualDeductibleAmount = " + familyAnnualDeductibleAmount);
            } else if (rdr.getLocalName().equals("FamilyAnnualOOPLimitAmount")) {
                rdr.nextTag();
                int familyAnnualOOPLimitAmount = Integer.parseInt(rdr.getElementText());
                System.out.println("FamilyAnnualOOPLimitAmount = " + familyAnnualOOPLimitAmount);
            }
        }
    }
    rdr.close();
```

Note that StAX is especially good for cases like yours, it skips all unnecessary elements reading only the ones you need