# How to ignore tags while reading text from XML?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XML text containing nested tags. The structure is somewhat complicated. So i have used `XPath` queries to access a child node as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13591396/848377). However, now I have encountered text within that node which itself contains XML tag. This method stops reading as soon as it encounters another XML tag.

Following is the XML file:

```
<x>
    <y>
        <z>
            This is a <tag>text</tag>
        </z>
    </y>
</x>
```

In the above XML, text inside `<z>` can be accessed by following method:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr= xpath.compile("/x/y/z/text()");
String text = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

But the value of text comes out to be **"This is a"** only. I want the whole text to be displayed : **This is a text**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `XPathExpression expr= xpath.compile("/x/y/z");`.

Comment: Following exception is received upon following this: `javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.`

Comment: Are you sure you get that error with the path `/x/y/z`? Sounds more like you have `/x/y/z/` or `/x/y/z//`. If you continue to have an error then edit your question with a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem, also tell us the Java version and XPath implementation you use.

Comment: Yes. I was using `/x/y/z/`. I have now rectified it and it works :)