# Java getElementsByTagName only get elements that are immediately under the given node

Tags: java, xml, getelementsbytagname

I am learning how to parse XML documents in Java and I noticed that getElementsByTagName Returns a NodeList of all descendant Elements with a given tag name, in document order. For example, if I have the following XML file

```
<Item>
    <peripherals>
        <peripheral>
            <Price> 100 </Price>
        </peripheral>
        <peripheral>
            <Price> 200 </Price>
        </peripheral>
    </peripherals>
    <Price> 500 </Price>
</Item>
```

If I try `getElementsByTagName("Price")` on Item node, it returns all 3 price Elements instead of just returning the one that is 500. How can I only get the price directly under Item node (In this example 500) ?

One way that comes to mind is to get all Price elements and then check the parent nodes but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591298/getting-value-of-child-node-from-xml-in-java

Comment: That post is about retrieving all the elements, I know how to do it with getElementsByTagName. What I am interested in is how do I get the only element that is directly under Item node and not get the Price elements under Peripheral nodes.

Comment: really, my reading of the answers is that they are selecting which nodes to get the value from - in your case you want Item/Price, so modify to `XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Item/Price/text()")`

Comment: I will try that, thank you.