# Freemarker template engine to retrieve data from xml

Tags: java, html, xml, xpath, freemarker

I have a xml with format say

```
<x>    
    <y>
        <z Name="z"> File Explorer </z>
    </y>
</x>
```

I want to write a freemarker template to retrieve the content "File Explorer".
I have written java code to transform xml to html.
input xml is given xml.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
 configuration.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        configuration.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource( new StringReader(xml.asXML()));
        root.put("doc", freemarker.ext.dom.NodeModel.parse(inputSource));
        result = new StringWriter();
        template.process(root, result);
```

I tried freemarker template with xpath

```
<span>${doc["x/y/z[@Name='z']"/]}</span>
```

But this on transforming displays
 ${doc["x/y/z[@Name='z']"/]}
instead of
File Explorer

Comment: Why do you have to use freemarker for this task? Why can't you use standard xml parser like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773012/getting-xml-node-text-value-with-java-dom (see the answer)?

Comment: If it indeed shows the `${...}` thing as is, then that file doesn't go through FreeMarker processing. (When it does, you will have to remove the last `/`, otherwise you get a FreeMarker syntax error.)

Comment: @ddekany Solved the issue. The problem was with java code to compile freemarker template. Should create template with method         Template template = new Template("name", new StringReader(), Configuration) instead. Now I am stuck with another issue. Does anyone have a clue on how to display content using xpath? In this example I have display "File Explorer" using Name attribute.

Comment: Isn't that what you are doing inside that `${...}`? Does it give an error, or what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Freemarker Ant task `freemarker.ext.ant.FreemarkerXmlTask`:

- Go to the `lib` folder which includes the freemarker JAR file
- Copy the path
- Paste it into the `location` attribute of the `pathElement` element of the Ant task
- Copy the path of the XML file
- Paste it into the attribute `basedir` in the `freemarker` element of the Ant task
- Copy the path of the FTL file
- Paste it into the `template` attribute of the `freemarker` element of the Ant task

For example:

- Ant task

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project basedir="." default="generate" name="FreeMarker-FAQ">

  <taskdef name="freemarker" classname="freemarker.ext.ant.FreemarkerXmlTask">
    <classpath> 
      <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="freemarker.jar"/>
      </fileset>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>

  <target name="generate">
    <mkdir dir="html"/>
    <freemarker basedir="." template="xml2html.ftl" includes="xml/data.xml" destdir="html"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

- XML file

data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root name="test" value="123">
  <child name="data" value="456"/>
</root>
```

- Freemarker Template

xml2html.ftl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>${.node.root.@name}</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="FreeMarker, Java, servlet, HTML, template, free software, open source, XML" />
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <h2><a name="top">${.node.root.child.@name}.</a></h2>
 </body>
</html>
```

- Directory structure
- build.xml

  - /lib

    - freemarker.jar
  - /html

    - data.html
  - /xml

    - data.xml

Then run `ant` from the directory which contains the `build.xml` file.

**References**

- [The Ant Task - FMPP](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/ant.html)
- [Using FreeMarker with Ant - Apache FreeMarker Manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_ant.html)
- [XML Processing Guide | Imperative XML processing | Details - Apache FreeMarker Manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_formal.html)
- [Download / Maven - Apache FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/freemarkerdownload.html)
- [Running Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#viajava)
- [Tutorial: Hello World with Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)
- [Apache Ant/Getting Started/Hello World - Wikibooks, open books for an open world](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Apache_Ant/Getting_Started/Hello_World)
- [neuland/FreemarkerValidatorTask: an Ant task that validates your Freemarker Templates](https://github.com/neuland/FreemarkerValidatorTask)