# How to read an XML file with Multiple group of element without attribute value in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

> I basically want to know how to get these element values from the xml
>   file in java set it into the Object.

Below are the sample XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <LoanApplication>
      <LoanId>1111</LoanId>
      <LoanStatus>Unsuccessful</LoanStatus>
      <LoanReference>111</LoanReference>
   </LoanApplication>
   <LoanApplication>
      <LoanId>222</LoanId>
      <LoanStatus>Unsuccessful</LoanStatus>
      <LoanReference>333</LoanReference>
   </LoanApplication>
   <LoanApplication>
      <LoanId>222</LoanId>
      <LoanStatus>Unsuccessful</LoanStatus>
      <LoanReference>4444</LoanReference>
   </LoanApplication>
   <LoanApplication>
      <LoanId>555</LoanId>
      <LoanStatus>Current</LoanStatus>
      <LoanReference>7777</LoanReference>
   </LoanApplication>
   <LoanApplication>
      <LoanId>3333</LoanId>
      <LoanStatus>Current</LoanStatus>
      <LoanReference>9999</LoanReference>
   </LoanApplication>
</Response>
```

Below are the Class where I want get xml data...

```
public class LoanIDResponse implements java.io.Serializable
{
private Integer loanID;
private Integer loanReference;
private String loanStatus;

public LoanIDResponse()
{
}
public void setLoanID(Integer loanID)
{
    this.loanID = loanID;
}

public void setLoanStatus(String loanStatus)
{
    this.loanStatus = loanStatus;
}

public void setLoanReference(Integer loanReference)
{
    this.loanReference = loanReference;
}
public Integer getLoanID()
{
    return loanID;
}

public Integer getLoanReference()
{
    return loanReference;
}

public String getLoanStatus()
{
    return loanStatus;
}
}
```

Below are the method where put some effort to parse xml file. Now I am struck how to set in my class setters.

```
 public Set<LoanIDResponse> getLoanIDList()
    {
        Set<LoanIDResponse> loanIDSet = new HashSet<>();
        try
        {

            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("Response.xml"));

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList listOfLoanApplication = doc.getElementsByTagName("LoanApplication");
            int totalLoanApplication = listOfLoanApplication.getLength();


            for (int s = 0; s < listOfLoanApplication.getLength(); s++)
            {

                Node loanApplicationNode = listOfLoanApplication.item(s);
                if (loanApplicationNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                    LoanIDResponse response = new LoanIDResponse();
                    Element loanApplicationElement = (Element) loanApplicationNode;

                    NodeList loanIDList = loanApplicationElement.getElementsByTagName("LoanId");

                    NodeList loanReferenceList = loanApplicationElement.getElementsByTagName("LoanReference");

                    NodeList loanStatusList = loanApplicationElement.getElementsByTagName("LoanStatus");

                }

            }

        } catch (SAXParseException err)
        {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "** Parsing error" + ", line {0}, uri {1}", new Object[]
            {
                err.getLineNumber(), err.getSystemId()
            });
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, " {0}", err.getMessage());

        }
        return loanIDSet;
    }
```

Comment: [Introduction to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/), [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/)

Comment: please tell us what efforts you made for implementing this, and what errors you are getting. StackOverflow is not about spoon feeding..

Comment: Now you can see my source code @Vishrant

Comment: @Z.U.H what error/ exception you are getting.

Comment: How to get the node value from tag @Vishrant

Comment: @Z.U.H after exploring your source code you can get like
NodeList nodeList = loanIDElement.getChildNodes();

Comment: Check if this question help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773012/getting-xml-node-text-value-with-java-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the node value like ...

```
 NodeList loanIDList = loanApplicationElement.getElementsByTagName("LoanId");
 Element loanIDElement = (Element) loanIDList.item(0);

 NodeList textIDList = loanIDElement.getChildNodes();
 response.setLoanID(Integer.parseInt(((Node)textIDList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim()));

//-------
 NodeList loanReferenceList = loanApplicationElement.getElementsByTagName("LoanReference");
 Element loanReferenceElement = (Element) loanReferenceList.item(0);

 NodeList textLRList = loanReferenceElement.getChildNodes();
 response.setLoanReference(Integer.parseInt(((Node) textLRList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim()));
//-------
 NodeList loanStatusList = loanApplicationElement.getElementsByTagName("LoanStatus");
 Element loanStatusElement = (Element) loanStatusList.item(0);

 NodeList textLSList = loanStatusElement.getChildNodes();
 response.setLoanStatus(((Node) textLSList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a look at [Introduction to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) and [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) for more details.

This example works on JAXB

First, you need some classes to hold your data

## LoanApplication

This is the basic properties of the loan application

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "LoanApplication")
public class LoanApplication {
    private long loanId;
    private String loanStatus;
    private long loadReference;

    public long getLoanId() {
        return loanId;
    }

    public String getLoanStatus() {
        return loanStatus;
    }

    public long getLoadReference() {
        return loadReference;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="LoanId")
    public void setLoanId(long loanId) {
        this.loanId = loanId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="LoanStatus")
    public void setLoanStatus(String loanStatus) {
        this.loanStatus = loanStatus;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="LoanReference")
    public void setLoadReference(long loadReference) {
        this.loadReference = loadReference;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getLoanId() + "; " + getLoanStatus() + "; " + getLoadReference();
    }
}
```

## Response

This is a "container" class which contains a list of `LoanApplications`

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
public class Response {

    private List<LoanApplication> applications;

    @XmlElement(name="LoanApplication")
    public void setApplications(List<LoanApplication> applications) {
        this.applications = applications;
    }

    public List<LoanApplication> getApplications() {
        return applications;
    }

}
```

## Reading...

Then we can read the XML file using something like...

```
try {
    File file = new File("Responses.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Response response = (Response) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    for (LoanApplication app : response.getApplications()) {
        System.out.println(app);
    }
} catch (JAXBException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

which based on the my example code, outputs

```
1111; Unsuccessful; 111
222; Unsuccessful; 333
222; Unsuccessful; 4444
555; Current; 7777
3333; Current; 9999
```

## Writing...

Writing is pretty much as the same as reading, in fact, for this example, it will include the reading portion as well, so we can update the content...

```
try {
    File file = new File("Responses.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Response response = (Response) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    for (LoanApplication app : response.getApplications()) {
        System.out.println(app);
    }

    LoanApplication app = new LoanApplication();
    app.setLoadReference(123456);
    app.setLoanId(7890);
    app.setLoanStatus("Approved");
    response.getApplications().add(app);

    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(response, new File("Responses.xml"));
    //jaxbMarshaller.marshal(response, System.out);
} catch (JAXBException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which generates...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Response>
    <LoanApplication>
        <LoanReference>111</LoanReference>
        <LoanId>1111</LoanId>
        <LoanStatus>Unsuccessful</LoanStatus>
    </LoanApplication>
    <LoanApplication>
        <LoanReference>333</LoanReference>
        <LoanId>222</LoanId>
        <LoanStatus>Unsuccessful</LoanStatus>
    </LoanApplication>
    <LoanApplication>
        <LoanReference>4444</LoanReference>
        <LoanId>222</LoanId>
        <LoanStatus>Unsuccessful</LoanStatus>
    </LoanApplication>
    <LoanApplication>
        <LoanReference>7777</LoanReference>
        <LoanId>555</LoanId>
        <LoanStatus>Current</LoanStatus>
    </LoanApplication>
    <LoanApplication>
        <LoanReference>9999</LoanReference>
        <LoanId>3333</LoanId>
        <LoanStatus>Current</LoanStatus>
    </LoanApplication>
    <LoanApplication>
        <LoanReference>123456</LoanReference>
        <LoanId>7890</LoanId>
        <LoanStatus>Approved</LoanStatus>
    </LoanApplication>
</Response>
```

*Note the last record is new*

I pretty much hobbled it together from [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) and [this example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/12/jaxb-tutorial-xml-binding.html)

Comment: I am to much impressed from answer... Excellent :)

Comment: @Z.I.J Wasn't to bad for 15 minutes of googling and hacking :P

Comment: I think this is not easy for new developers..  Thanks for sharing valuable answer and comment.. Can I make you friend any other forum?

Comment: @Z.I.J :) Sorry, this is the only place a haunt

Comment: as you wish.. I am sad to see your sorry.. :P